# Delete OLD version before installating new version of iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I have an application on AppStore. On releasing a new version on appstore, I want that user should be asked to remove the old version and then install the new version when he tries to install new version on an existing version of the application.
Can anybody tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Ashwani

Comment: This is an extremely bad design decision, because of how unfriendly it is to users.  I don't even see the need for an action like this.  The user's preferences and other information should persist across upgrades.  For version-specific information or databases, you should contain that as read-only resources within the application bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have that kind of control over the install process.  You could ask the user to do it in your release notes.

Why would you want to do this?  You may be better off resolving your issue, rather than try to figure out a way to force an app delete.